# Set value in related model with ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

I have these four models all related by ManyToManyFields:

> A *<-->* B *<-->* C *<-->* D

Given an A object I need to set a value in its related field in D.

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    # Get all foo, from differents B, C and D
    @property
    def get_all_foo(self):
        for b in B.objects.filter(...):
            for c in C.objects.filter(...):
                foo = ';'.join([d.foo for d in D.objects.filter(...)])
        return foo

    def set_foo(self, value):
        # the code I need

class B(models.Model):
    a = ManyToManyField(A)

class C(models.Model):
    b = ManyToManyField(B)

class D(models.Model):
    c = ManyToManyField(C)
    foo = models.TextField()
```

What I need is to set the value of *foo* in D from a function in A (the same way I get all the values from it). How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your `get_all_foo` method is incredibly inefficient, potentially causing thousands of separate database calls. Replace it with:

```
return ';'.join(D.objects.filter(c__b__a__=self).values_list('foo'))
```

You can use the same principle to update the D objects from A:

```
D.objects.filter(c__b__a__=self).update(foo=value)
```

Comment: Definitely more efficient but I wonder if it changes the results the op gets from that method since foo is overwritten every iteration. It probably should be what you've shown here though